# How do I get a projection from a MongoDB database quickly with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, pymongo, projection

I have a collection of 286484 documents, `collection`, each one of which contains many fields, but in particular they all contain a `title` and a `pmid`. I wish to get a dictionary that maps pmids to titles.

I expected this to be approximately instantaneous given the moderate amount of data. Instead, the below code reports a runtime of approximately 330.1 sec.

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
papers = collection.find(projection={"_id": False, "title": True, "pmid": True})
papers2 = {paper["pmid"]: paper["title"] for paper in papers}
stop = time.perf_counter()
print(f"elapsed time: {stop - start} sec")
```

Why does this take so long, and how do I speed it up?

Other relevant facts:

- I'm running in Python 3.7.6 on linux with pymongo 3.12.1 and MongoDB 4.4.0.
- I've verified that the projection works correctly (i.e. it returns `pmid` and `title` and nothing else).
- This is all running on a single cloud machine (i.e. database and code on same machine, no sharding). It's not particularly high powered, but there's free memory and no other simultaneous users.
- `pmid` is indexed; `title` is not.
- `explain` doesn't really help here because there's no filter. The `winningPlan` is `PROJECTION_SIMPLE` and there are no `rejectedPlans`. A possible clue: calling `explain` on the cursor took 440 sec.

Comment: Since you are reading all documents in a collection, the read is slower. Generally, index become useful with filter (conditions) and sort operations.

Comment: I agree, but this is scanning at only 1000 items a second. That's really slow.

Comment: Here is some relevant information in this SO post: [MongoDB Indexing and Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286908/mongodb-indexing-and-projection).

Comment: Your time counter measurement may not be correct about measuring the query performance. Query is executed on the database server - that doesn't include time to send the query to the server, bring back query results back, process it, etc.